# How to daemonize django celery periodic task on ubuntu server?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

On localhost, i used these statements to execute tasks and workers.
Run tasks:
python manage.py celery beat
Run workers:
python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info
I used otp, rabbitmq server and django-celery.
It is working fine.
I uploaded the project on ubuntu server. I would like to daemonize these. 
For that i created a file /etc/default/celeryd as below config settings.

```
# Name of nodes to start, here we have a single node
CELERYD_NODES="w1"
# or we could have three nodes:
#CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"
# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/sandbox/myprojrepo/myproj"

# How to call "manage.py celeryd_multi"
CELERYD_MULTI="$CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryd_multi"

# How to call "manage.py celeryctl"
CELERYCTL="$CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryctl"

# Extra arguments to celeryd
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"
```

## Name of the celery config module.

```
CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE="celeryconfig"

# %n will be replaced with the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"

# Name of the projects settings module.
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings"
```

Also i created a file /etc/init.d/celeryd with script i downloaded.

Now when i try to execute /etc/init.d/celeryd start it gives error as Unrecogonized command line argument. 
I issued "celeryd-multi start nodeN" as a command and it said nodeN started. But tasks execution havent started yet.

I am new to daemonizing and server hosting.

Answer (score 2):

You can run celery within supervisor:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/supervisor
http://thomassileo.com/blog/2012/08/20/how-to-keep-celery-running-with-supervisor/

hth.