# Using Celery with Django

Tags: python, django, celery

I am trying to automate some tasks(like email, calculating rank etc of my django app using celery(not django-celery) . I tried following the tutorials given in official documentation but, I couldn't understand it completely. I learnt how I can call the tasks from the shell but running the tasks in background after specific time-intervals is not explained. I googled for tutorials but they are outdated and use django-celery not just celery. So, could someone, please, explain it with a few examples showing step-by-step process. I want celery to be running in background and doing the tasks at specified intervals. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153425/how-to-daemonize-django-celery-periodic-task-on-ubuntu-server

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Periodic tasks, run tasks after some time...?

Comment: Tasks run in fixed period of time and also adding emails to a queue and send them asynchronously.